# Using Bot Framework Composer with Audiocodes Voice AI Gateway

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

I created a simple Bot with Bot Framework Composer and connected it to the Direct Line API

Via Web Chat I can receive the Welcome message as expected

Now I want to use the Audiocodes Voice AI Gateway to create a Voicebot. The integration is described here:
https://www.audiocodes.com/media/14549/voiceai-gateway-integration-guide.pdf

My problem is, that the call is not answered. I can see the ActivityEvent coming in, but it seems that the response send by the bot is not working.

Could it be the case, that the standard send response which is build via LG-format is conflicting with the json format that the Voice AI-Gateway is expecting:

{
 "type": "message",
 "text": "Hi, how may I assist you?"
}

Is there a chance to override the LG Format and send a custom JSON ?

Additionally I would like to understand, if it is possible to get access to the plain json data that is coming from the Audiocodes Gateway to post it in a body to an external HTTP Server.

Any hints would be appreciated